# TestNG executes beforesuite method of the last test first always when initializing the multiple test cases declared in a test suite

Tags: java, automation, testng

In summary, I have 2 tests declared in a test suite as below however the testng runner executes the beforesuite method of the last test always. This results in the test reports shows there are 3 tests executed which is not expected. By trailing the code, I found the privateRun() overrides the beforesuite method for the last test because it iterates itselft for the 2 testRunners.

Please advise how I can run the beforesuite always for the first test instance, not the last one of the suite.

Here is the test structure.

**Test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="suiteA">
<test name="T1">
        <classes>
            <class name="C1"/>
            <class name="C2"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
<test name="T2">
        <classes>
            <class name="C3"/>
            <class name="C4"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

**Test Run**

```
Suite A
     T2 *(this doesn't run any tests other than Beforesuite)*
    >T1
    >T2
```